# How can I get gdb to disassemble an entire function?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, att

When I write things in assembly that involve jumps, I do something along the lines of:

```
fucntion: 
  cmp $1, %rax
  je cond
  mov $0 %rdi
  jmp end
cond:
  mov $1, %rdi
end:
  mov $60, %rax
  syscall
```

The problem is that when I use gdb and type `disas function` I will only see `function` up until `cond`. However, if I were to write a similar c program, jump statements in the disassembled program would look like `jmp ADDRESS <function+xx>` and typing `disas function` will show me every line of the function.

How can I get gdb to behave similarly with my assembly programs? Is there a flag with the assembler or linker that would make the program's jumps look more like the c program? Or would I have to change the way I write assembly? Basically I just want to be able to type `disas function` and get the entire function outputted.

Comment: Try putting ‘.’ as the first character of the local symbol names.

Comment: @prl Do you mean I would write `.cond:` instead of `cond:`?

Comment: @AAJ Yes.  Except, it actually needs to be `.L`.  All labels beginning with `.L` are local labels that aren't placed in the symbol table.  Refer to the GNU assembler manual for details.

Comment: @fuz Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to specify the extent of your function.
Append

```
.size function, . - function
```

at the end.

Comment: You should also add `.type   function, @function` while you are at it.